# Why is Console Layout not listed?

Tags: configuration, developer

I have a developer edition Salesforce org and I want to create a [Console Layout](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=console_creating_layouts.htm&language=en_US) but I cannot find it listed in Build > Customize > Agent Console, as specified in the link above. I have another developer account where it is available. Are there circumstances that make these components unavailable and if so, how can I change this?
PS: I made sure I have the "edit application" permission.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to do the setup and/or missing some step in the setup for Agent Console. Please refer to this link:

https://rakeshistom.wordpress.com/2014/04/04/setting-up-live-agent-in-salesforce/

Comment: I did this already but I still cannot access the Console Layout

Comment: I have the same issue, trying to figure out the missing setup now.