# Unable to find console layout options

Tags: service-cloud-console, page-layout

I've got a Developer Edition and I'm trying to setup service cloud console and get some canvas apps running in it. According to the document [here](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=console_manage_layouts.htm&language=en_US), I should be able to find the console layouts in the quick find box, but I'm not able to.

I have the System Administrator profile and verified that the "Customize Application" privilege is checked.

Does anyone else come across this before? Any help?

P.S: I can find some layout options under Case Layout > Custom Console Components, but it doesn't seem to work.
Another question "[Why is Console Layout not listed?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/70646/why-is-console-layout-not-listed)" but hasn't got any proper answers.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the Service Cloud User checkbox on your own user record is checked (API name of this field is UserPermissionSupportUser).

The link you provided is to the 'Agent Console', which is an older product which is being mothballed (no longer available to new orgs from Spring '15 according to [this](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=console_setup.htm&language=en_US)).

The Salesforce Console implementation guide you want is [here](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/200/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_console_impl_guide.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for the information about "Agent Console", I will check the console implementation guide and get back.